# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'select' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, xampp

```
$sql=''select Name from users where Username='$username' and 

Password='$password'";
```

Comment: remove the last double quote from the statement

Comment: Don't confuse two single quotes with one double quote; [learn about the differences](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: $sql=''select Name from users where Username='$username' and

Password='$password' ";      i tried this also

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRYTjl8xspA                                           
 i tried to implement this video exactly how it is . but encountered the above error. cud there be an error with xampp server?

Comment: because only values are getting inserted into db . but it is not being retrieved or fetched from db for performing login validation.

Comment: Your query should be parameterized.

Answer (score 1):

You have some double-quote and single-quote mixup in your code. Always match them in correct order as you use them.

You query can be corrected as:

```
$sql = "select Name from users where Username='$username' and Password='$password' ";
```

I have put an extra space before the last double quote, just to clarify the use of single and double quote in that place.

Comment: Right, but did you see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758252/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-select-t-string#comment80461784_46758252) the OP left? *"$sql=''select Name from users where Username='$username' and Password='$password' "; i tried this also "*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The code in that comment is syntactically wrong as the quotes before `select` are "two single quotes', not a single double-quote. Thats why its giving error to the user.

Comment: Yeah, I see that in my editor now. Their comment appeared as containing an opening double quote, which was a bit hard to read in there. That comment and the post itself are the same.

Comment: Yes, I checked that comment code in an editor too, thats why posted an explanatory answer, which wasn't possible for me to mention in a comment. :-)